# Facing difficulties while installing node.js and npm in mac

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to install node.js and npm in mac mini.

I have gone through lot of tutorials. Sometimes it is getting installed and unable to use it. Now I am installing using Homebrew.

```
nbmacmini9:~ afsarunnisa$ brew install node
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-0.12.7.yosemite.bottle
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring node-0.12.7.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man1/node.1
Target /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7: 2726 files, 31M
nbmacmini9:~ afsarunnisa$ node -v
-bash: node: command not found
```

I am unable to check whether node is installed or not. Again I have tried to install node.js then it is like this:

```
nbmacmini9:~ afsarunnisa$ brew install node
Warning: node-0.12.7 already installed, it's just not linked
nbmacmini9:~ afsarunnisa$ node -v
-bash: node: command not found
nbmacmini9:~ afsarunnisa$
```

Comment: For me it worked just to call `brew link --overwrite node`

Comment: If you haven't figured out the problem yet, run `brew doctor`, which should provide you some clues as to what's going wrong with your installation. It's not uncommon to have other software (that you installed in cellar without using homebrew) cause installation issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the below step

```
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1'
```

first remove using above comment and try again. Also for mac you can install node directly from the [package](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.pkg)